# API is not triggered with value from AutocompleteInput / React Admin

Tags: input, autocomplete, react-admin

I am using Autocomplete input and trying to send choices value to the api.

Please find my code as below:

```
export const PostFilter_Search = (props) => {
const dp = useDataProvider();
const [acTypeValue, setAcType] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    dp.getCustomUrl(`/DefectMelDraftNexts`)
        .then(response => {
            var items: any[] = response.data.items;

            var temp = items.filter((thing, i, arr) => {
                return arr.indexOf(arr.find(t => t.acType === thing.acType)) === i;
            })

            setAcType(Object.assign(acTypeValue, temp));
        });
}, [])
return (
    <Filter {...props} >

        <AutocompleteInput label="AcType" source="acType" translateChoice={false} allowEmpty={false} 
            choices={acTypeValue}
            optionText="acType"
            optionValue="acType"
        />
    </Filter >

)
```

};

choices is as below:

```
 0:
 acSeries: "RR-XWB"
 acSn: "0403 0421 0435 0442 0454 0496"
 acType: "A350"
 catRating: null
 chapter: "42"
 __proto__: Object
```

acType is the value which is needed to be sent to the api for filtering.

However, filter is sent to the api as filter=(acType) but not sent with the selected value. For example; filter=(acType=A350).

Could you please help me?

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved with below code:

```
 export const PostFilter_Search = (props) => {
 const dp = useDataProvider();
 const [acTypeValue, setAcType] = useState<any[]>([]);
 const [melNumberValue, setMelNumber] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    dp.getCustomUrl(`/DefectMelDraftNexts`)
        .then(response => {
            var items: any[] = response.data.items;

            var temp_acType = items.filter((thing, i, arr) => {
                return arr.indexOf(arr.find(t => t.acType === thing.acType)) === i;
            })

            var temp_melNumber = items.filter((thing, i, arr) => {
                return arr.indexOf(arr.find(t => t.melNumber === thing.melNumber)) === i;
            })

            setAcType(Object.assign(melNumberValue, temp_melNumber));
            setAcType(Object.assign(acTypeValue, temp_acType));

        });
}, [])
return (
    <Filter {...props} >

        <AutocompleteInput label="Mel Number" source="DefectMelDraftNexts.any(v => v.MelNumber == $)" translateChoice={false} allowEmpty={false}
            choices={melNumberValue}
            optionText="melNumber"
            optionValue="melNumber"
        />

        <AutocompleteInput label="AcType" source="DefectMelDraftNexts.any(v => v.AcType == $)" translateChoice={false} allowEmpty={false}
            choices={acTypeValue}
            optionText="acType"
            optionValue="acType"
        />


    </Filter >

)
```

};